# Calling Moodle functions from PHP over SOAP

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, moodle

I am having difficulty getting started with interfacing my PHP script to [Moodle](http://www.moodle.org) 2.0 over the SOAP Web Service provided.  Not knowing much about SOAP, I figured I would simply connect and go from there.  However, I can't even get connected...

```
$soap=new SoapClient(
    'http://mymoodleserver/webservice/xmlrpc/server.php?wstoken=asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf',
    array(
        'trace'=>1,
        'exceptions'=>true,
        'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    )
);
```

This returns:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load...

If I were to go to this URL directly, no data is returned.  Looking at it with Fiddler shows that the server does indeed return a Content-Length of 0.

There isn't any documentation on this that I could find... there is [documentation for other protocols](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Development%3aCreating_a_web_service_client) however.

I am assuming that the [SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) is expecting some WSDL to define what functions are available.  I have a list of those functions and parameters (no thanks to the [official documentation page](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Development%3aWeb_services_API_-_Function_List)).  How can I instruct SoapClient to not worry about the WSDL and carry on?

I have checked for errors in the PHP error log on the Moodle server, and it turned up clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to use the non wsdl mode is to add it to the uri

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "http://localhost/soap.php",
                                     'uri'      => "http://test-uri/"));
```

Ofocurse, use trace and then look for getlastrequest and getlastresponse

```
$result = $client->SomeFunction();
echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php

Use xmlspy for easy debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The key is in the error, so I started looking at the documentation for Moodle knowing what to expect, no WSDL.

Check the documentation for [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) and the [documentation for Moodle](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Development%3aCreating_a_web_service_client) as you can see Moodle doesnt offer [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) so you need to use the SoapClient in [non-WSDL mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php).